# $lookup in aggregation Mongoose, Should we use two fields in foreignField?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

Let's Take I've two collections one is `abc` another is `xyz`. Those have follow documents. Mongo 3.4 only

abc

```
[
  {
    _id: 12345,
    name: test
  }
]
```

xyz

```
[
  {
    _id: 234234ssfd,
    name: test,
    xyzId: 12345,
    flag: true
  },
  {
    _id: sdfsd445454545,
    name: test123,
    xyzId: 12345,
    flag: false
  }
]
```

Query Which I used.

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $lookup:{ 
            "from": "xyz", 
            "localField": "_id", 
            "foreignField": "xyzId", 
            "as": "xyz"
        }
    } ])
```

When I used above query It returns me both result from `xyz` but I want something like to check `flag` also and want to remove from that result.Is that possible in `$lookup` or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your pipeline and add filtering by `flag` (works in 3.6)

```
Model.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "xyz",
           let: { abc_id: "$_id" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$$abc_id",  "$xyzId" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$flag", true ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "xyz"
         }
    }
])
```

In 3.4 you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to post-process `$lookup` results:

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
      $lookup:{ 
          "from": "xyz", 
          "localField": "_id", 
          "foreignField": "xyzId", 
          "as": "xyz"
      }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      xyz: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$xyz",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [ "$$item.flag", true ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
 ])
```

Comment: "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { abc_id: \"$_id\" } is type object"   Mongo 3.4.6

Comment: @higunjan added 3.4 solution with $filter since you can't use `pipeline` in 3.4.6

Comment: True. Accepted.